# Where are my Menu Items coming from?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've taken over this website with no documentation (Yay!).  Maybe this will help others to understand the SiteMap functionality.  I have an idea how the SiteMenu is being built, but want to check with my buddies here at SO to be sure.

I have a Main.Master which calls for a SiteMenuHorizontal User Control.

```
<%@ Register Src="uc2Menu.ascx" TagPrefix="uc2" TagName="smHorizontal" %>
...
<uc2:smHorizontal id="uc2Menu" runat="server" />
```

The User Control is pretty simple:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="uc2Menu.ascx.vb" Inherits="uc2Menu" %>
<asp:Menu id="siteMenu" runat="server" DataSourceID="menuSiteMapDataSource" Orientation="Horizontal" />

<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="menuSiteMapDataSource" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" />
```

No help from the control's codebehind:

```
Public Partial Class uc2Menu
Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

Protected Sub siteMenu_MenuItemDataBound(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuEventArgs) Handles siteMenu.MenuItemDataBound
    e.Item.Target = CType(e.Item.DataItem, SiteMapNode)("Target")
End Sub
End Class
```

The Web.Config DOES specify a SiteMap:

```
<siteMap enabled="true" defaultProvider="objSiteMap">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="objSiteMap" type="LOC.DLL.objSiteMap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" expirationInterval="1"/>
    </providers>
</siteMap>
```

LOC.DLL.objSiteMap inherits SiteMapProvider and has overloads/overrides etc.  The methods grab a table from a DB and build a SiteMapNode, or SiteMapNodeCollection.

My confusion is: How is this class populating my web page?  There are no visible calls to the SiteMap.

My assumption is this:
When the site (or page) is built (or compiled?), my User Control calls its Datasource, Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.SiteMapDataSource.  Somehow, that control references the Web.Config for a reference to LOC.DLL.objSiteMap, and runs the Override/Overload methods to retrieve a SiteMapNode(/Collection), and return it back to my control?

I have a feeling I've got it down, but wanted to get a confirmation and/or clarification, and hopefully help others in the future who take over projects with dynamic site menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is this class populating my web page?  There are no visible calls
>   to the SiteMap.

SiteMapProvider is based on [ASP.Net's Provider model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479030.aspx), similar to Membership and Role providers.

> My assumption is this: When the site (or page) is built (or
>   compiled?),  my User Control calls its Datasource,
>   Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls. SiteMapDataSource. Somehow, that
>   control references the Web.Config for  a reference to
>   LOC.DLL.objSiteMap, and runs the Override/Overload methods to retrieve
>   a SiteMapNode(/Collection), and return it  back to my control?

Yes, your assumption is correct.

Your user control calls the default site map provider `objSiteMap`, and the sitemap is created on every page request dynamically.

**FYI:** Since you have set `objSiteMap` as the defaultprovider, you do not need to do anything. However, if you want a provider other than the default, you'll need to set a provider name explicitly.

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" 
 SiteMapProvider="AnotherProvider" />
```

Comment: @jdarnel27 - Now I know how to use `Backquote` properly. Thank you for the edit.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you learn to use the blockquote syntax!

Comment: Thank for adding clarification on the SiteMapProvider property, that will certainly help anybody needing that.  What would really top off this answer would be to say when the SiteMapDataSource is executed.  In this type of situation, there is a source, a DAL, and a UI (I actually also have a Web Service inbetween, but that's indifferent for this discussion)  As far as my reference has found, SiteMapDataSource is cached when the website starts.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty much right on the money with your analysis.

The main connection here that I think you're missing is that the web.config value `defaultProvider="objSiteMap"` is what causes the `SiteMapDataSource` in your UserControl to connect to the "objSiteMap" provider in your web.config.

Since it is set as the "default provider", any SiteMap's in your project will be populated using that `LOC.DLL.objSiteMap` provider (unless you specifically override the default in the code).

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  Good catch on the defaultProvider property.

Comment: @Suamere Thanks!  I'm glad I could help =)  I know it's easy to miss things like that when you're wading through a new project with no documentation (I've definitely been there before).